# Dog behavioural changes on gabapentin

Tags: dogs, medicines

Has anyone got dogs taking gabapentin, particularly for back pain, who have noticed any behavioural changes? My 12 year old Canaan dog has been on gabapentin for a few months now for spondylitis (stiff vertebrae), but it's hard to detect any changes over such a long time.

He's been slowing down over the last year or so, and the vet thinks back pain may be the cause. But I can't really say whether the medication is having any effect on his activity. Tiredness is a side effect of the drug, and I'm happy for him to be tired and in less pain, but I'm wondering whether others have had similar experiences.

Answer (score 1):

Gabapentin can cause sedation but the sedative side effects are usually transient. That being said, there are many medications that can treat chronic pain, and it may be a good idea to switch, but with gabapentin in particular, make sure you switch off of it gradually to minimize withdrawal, as it has a short half-life.